# How to run a function right after the scroll position is restored in a browser window?

Tags: javascript, browser, window, scrollbar

After the page is reloaded (or history state is changed) the browser by default restores a scroll position.
In some browsers it happens with a delay (scroll jumps from top to persisted position).
What is the best way to run a callback right after the initial scroll position is set?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the delayed jumping your describing is due to the `window` or `document` resizing as it loads to fit its content.

You should be able to detect this on its `resize` event. However, if want to initialize or load content nicely you actually want to know when the element becomes visible - for this, you can use an [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/observe).

Personally, I find a quick and easy way to prevent flashing/jumping when loading content is to simply apply a CSS animation to it and the browser will detect the inersection for you.